# Can you make a Gaussian-weighted superposition state with polynomially many gates?

Tags: quantum-computation

Suppose I have N register qubits, so they can represent the range [0, 2^N-1].  They are initialized in the all-zeroes state. I want my final state to approximate
$$|\phi \rangle = \frac{1}{2^{2^N-1}} \sum_{m=0}^{2^N-1} {2^N-1 \choose m} |m \rangle \, .$$
Can this be done with poly(N) 2-qubit + 1-qubit gates? How good an approximation can I get with poly(N) gates?

Comment: Do you allow for ancilla qubits? Then you could use those as coins to perform a classical random walk, which would give you a normal distribution, which your distribution also approaches for large $2^N$ (so it only requires moderately-sized $N$).

Comment: I don't want a distribution; I don't want my state to be randomly entangled with ancillary qubits.  I want a pure state as above.

Comment: Right right, so you want some sort of diffusion process that's still coherent. For spins you can achieve that with a Hamiltonian quadratic in the generators (like $H=J_z+J_x^2$) but I might hesitate before counting the number of qubit gates you'd need to simulate that